# Javascript array output

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following code I need two things:

1. This one I know how to do, basically user inputs a number and matching month is provided in an output.
2. But in the same prompt if user writes a month (for eksample "Aug"), how do I return the index number?

The first part I would solve with a for loop and if/else, but how do I include also the second part with only one prompt from user?

```
var months = ["Not in use", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"];

var userInput = prompt("Choose a month by number or name!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a check on the input value and return response accordingly:

```js
let months = ["Not in use", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"];

let locator = v => Number.isNaN(Number(v)) ? months.indexOf(v) : months[v];

console.log(locator("Aug"));
console.log(locator("3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an empty first element in the array you should add 1 to the index. Next you should check if the userInput is one of the months and change it to the index of the month + 1.

```
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"]
let userInput = prompt("Choose a month by number or name!");
if (months.include(userInput) {
    userInput = months[userInput + 1]
}
```

In addition you have to turn the user input wich is a string into an integer if it is within the range between 1 and 12

```
let parsedInt = parseInt(userInput)
if (parsedInt >= 1 && parsedInt <= 12) {
    userInput = parsedInt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of your user prompt with a `if/else`.

```
let userInput = prompt('Choose a month by number or name')
let monthNumber = parseInt(userInput)
if (monthNumber === NaN) {
    // Do your stuff using userInput as a monthName
} else {
    // Do your stuff using monthNumber
}
```